Display only one column for one of the values in pivot table
In my pivot table there is one column labeled 'Week' and two values: 'Sales and 'KPI'. I would like to display 'Sales' for all weeks but show the 'KPI' only for the last week. Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to hiding columns?

What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this?
